# How do you hack Spectres?

Tags: titanfall-2

Very early in the single player campaign, I saw a hint in one of the loading screens that I can hack enemy Spectres to fight on my side. I faintly remember to have read somewhere that I have to get behind a Spectre (preferably using cloak) and use my data knife, but that never seemed to work.

The only mission I actually managed to hack a Spectre was the mission where you get the Arc tool, which fires electricity and disables Spectres for a moment. Then, when I got behind them, I got a prompt "Press E to hack Spectre" or similar almost every time

However, this didn't work again the following missions. So am I missing something crucial? I'm playing on PC.

**Edit:**

I just realized that there are also Stalkers, which can't be hacked. Did I maybe mix those two up and that is the source of my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to hack Spectres by getting behind them and pressing E. Stalkers can't be hacked.

Spectres are about the same height as Pilots or slightly taller, whereas Stalkers are noticeably taller.

Comment: Do they have to in a certain state for that? Like disabled, not alarmed, etc.?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only requirement is that you're behind them. Oh, and you can _sort of_ hack Stalkers, but only when they're attached to their stand, later in the game when you're given another device

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it whilst being shot at either, as it takes a few seconds. Use your cloak and hack Spectres, then get away whilst the Spectre takes fire

Comment: I can confirm Spectres can be hacked in titanfall 2, as I successfully hacked one. I had forgot that was even an option, usually they just get the business end of the muzzle instead :P